# Docker Registry EOF erros

Tags: docker, circleci

I keep getting failed tests in CircleCi stating:

```
Pulling postgres (postgres:12)...
ERROR: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: EOF
```

I am not sure how to debug this and occasionally I appear to be getting other similar messages while other items are pulling from docker hub while deploying manually on my servers. Is the docker registry down, nothing appears to be on the forum?

I just got a different one from a base image:

```
ERROR: Service 'celery' failed to build: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/python/manifests/3.8.5-slim-buster: EOF
```

Comment: Started seeing this yesterday, looked like it had cleared up, but now seems to be back. I've opened an issue on Hub, this is better tracked over there: https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/2082

Comment: @BMitch okay thanks, I thought I was going crazy. At least this is something seen by others, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a partial outage at Docker Hub. They are reporting that it's been fixed now. For anyone encountering issues in the future, good places to go to check the current status on Hub include:

- https://status.docker.com/
- https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback
- https://twitter.com/Docker